# Split function in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Where i have to pass the split function in JMeter?
I want to split the string such as V_12 I want the V for the if controller so how can I do this I tried to like this but it is not splitting the string

```
${__split(v_12,test_2,_)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're following proper syntax for variable names, etc. See the [documentation of the `split` function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split).

Also, you'd want to place it before the If controller as part of a beanshell script, OR as the logic for the IF controller.

Answer (score 1):

See :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

You would use
${__split(v_12, varName, _)}

Then access $varName_1 which would contain v